# Detect if at least a cell in a DataGridView is selected or not

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I've a form with a DataGridView and a BindingNavigator with toolStripButton. 
So I need to disable a BindingNavigator's ToolStripButton when any cell is selected and enable it when at least one cell is selected. 
I've tried with CellClick event and SelectionChanged event but i can't solve this issue.

```
private void myDataGridView_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
if (myGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "findValueDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"
                   || myDataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "replaceValueDataGridViewTextBoxColumn")
                {
                    myDropDownButton.Enabled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                   myDropDownButton.Enabled = false;
                }
}
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: Can you show you code, perhaps may be we can edit for you ?

Comment: What do you mean by "selected"?  If you mean it in the proper sense then it should be obvious that the `SelectedCells` collection is the place to look.  If you mean something else then it would help to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Use index instead of name and DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs instead of DataGridViewCellEventArgs.

Example

```
private void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    string msg = String.Format("Editing Cell at ({0}, {1})",
        e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex);
//You go to your datagrid and identify the index of the replaceValueDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
//e.g Int ColIndex1 = replaceValueDataGridViewTextBoxColumn index 0 fro the first , 1 for second etc.
  if(e.ColumnIndex  = ColIndex1  || e.ColumnIndex = ColIndex2)
  {
      myDropDownButton.Enabled = true;
   }
   // this.Text = msg;
}
```

In your case

```
private void myDataGridView_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
//get the column index of your columns 
//Here you dont need to call grid name just e is enough 
//Note you can try e.Name may be , but i didn't 
if (e.ColumnIndex == colIndex1 || e.ColumnIndex == colIndex2)
    {
           myDropDownButton.Enabled = true;
     }
  else
     {
            myDropDownButton.Enabled = false;
       }
}
```

or Try like below, put a break point and see the value of colName.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseEnter(object sender,
    DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   string colName= (string)dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name
}
```

Please check [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs.columnindex(v=vs.110).aspx) and      [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) for full explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SelectedCells` property of `DataGridView`:

```
if (myDataGridView.SelectedCells.Count > 1) // at least one cell selected
{
   //do somethings
}
```